# How to use Autosklearn with dask dataframe?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dask, auto-sklearn

How can I use dask dataframe in Autosklearn?

My code is correct and working using the Pandas dataframe but not working with Dask.
I'm using the Dask dataframe because my dataset is very large.

Is there any autosklearn support for dask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is support for autosklearn with Dask, [here](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/examples/60_search/example_parallel_manual_spawning_python.html) are some helpful docs from autosklearn

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this into dataframe by ref to the link below
[click here](https://examples.dask.org/dataframe.html)

After converting it into df you can use it with sklearn

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import pandas as pd
```

We’ll use scikit-learn to create a pair of small random arrays, one for the features X, and one for the target y.

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, random_state=0)
X[:5]
```

Reference link:
[click here](https://examples.dask.org/machine-learning.html)